# iOS Apps Launches but immediately closes on iPad

Tags: ios, delphi, launch

I have 3 iOS apps developed originally with Delphi Berlin then Tokyo and now with Rio.

Since updating to Delphi Rio (10.3.1) each of these apps close immediately after launch.

These apps will compile and install via Mac to iPad (12.1.4) but when they launch, they immediately close.  I suppose they are crashing.   However, I have compiled and uploaded the exact same apps to the App Store and when the apps are downloaded and installed from App Store they run perfectly. They simply will not run under Development install on any iOS device I have tried.

I am running Delphi 10.3.1, PAServer 20, iOS 12.1.4 on iPad and XCode 10.1 on the Mac.

Previously on Delphi Tokyo I could compile these exact same apps and they ran fine on the iPad.  I even created a simple new app with nothing but a label and I get the same results.

Does anyone have any suggestion or ideas as I have tried everything I can think of?

Comment: add crashlytics in that app so that you can track the crashes

Comment: My first suggestion would be to use a debugger so that you don't have to *suppose they are crashing*, but know for sure what they're doing. Once you've established that, you can maybe figure out why whatever is happening is happening.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the certificate you use for your debug version?

Comment: "when the apps are downloaded and installed from App Store they run perfectly". On exactly the same device where it crashes when debugging?

Comment: Yes, the exact app uploaded to app store can be downloaded on to the exact same device and runs fine.  So strange.  I run the app on 14 ipads in our company vehicles.  I updated with very minor change and installed update on all of the ipads and they run fine.  But when I install on ipad via mac it installs but on launch it closes after showing loading icon.  Have not been able to get debugging to work. I have removed and recreated certificates but that has not made a difference.  Thanks to all suggestions and if anyone has further ideas please let me know.

Comment: I suggest running the Console app (in Applications/Utilities on the Mac), selecting the device and using a filter (top right corner) of the app name as it appears in the IDE, then debug the app again, and look at the last few messages in Console when the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.  Found the "Trusted" properties of the signing certificate on the the Mac had to be edited.  This resolved the problem. Went to Utilities / Key Chains / My Certificates, selected the certificate and changed from Trusted to "Use System Defaults".  This resolved the issue completely and now the apps run correctly.